# how to rewire from a light fixture to a switch outlet

Tags: electrical

I have an outlet that power comes into from breaker and the outlet wires to other outlets and goes to a switch that i would like to run a light fixture from the switch, i already ran cable to the ceiling box to the switch. in the switch box there is a black and white and ground. And in the outlet box has black and white wire on top outlet and same on bottom outlet with the bottom black wire going to a group of black wires that run another outlet and has a single white wire that comes from the breaker.

Comment: Can you post photos of the situation inside the boxes?

Comment: You currently have a situation with a switched outlet that is split.  The switch is straightforward enough.  But to suoport it, we will need to rearrange things a bit in the receptacle area, so a picture of that will be most crucial.

Answer (score 0):

Kinda speculating here since you haven't gotten back with us.  But it sounds like the switch is currently a switch loop, and white is one of the hots.  We're gonna change all that.   And there are a total of 3 cables going to the receptacle: this switch loop, supply, and onward power to another receptacle.

Ok, so all ground wires get joined everywhere we go. All grounds are pigtailed, not using a device as a splice.   Every switch and receptacle gets a pigtail and that gets added to the ground bundle.  Probably already that way. And hook up the grounds first.

**In the switch**, tie both white wires together with a wire nut and push them into the back of the box.  The two blacks remaining (including your new one) go to the 2 terminals on the switch.

**Pull out the receptacle** and notice how there are tabs between the screws that can be broken off.   It'll be broken off on the side with the brass screws (the hot).   Put a black pigtail on each brass screw.  Put a white pigtail on one of the silver screws.

**In the receptacle box**, the changes you made cause a happy coincidence, now all the wire colors in this box actually match. All blacks are always-hot, and all whites are now neutral.    Join all the white wires with a wirenut.  Join all the black wires with a wirenut.

And you're done.